# Create bezier curved with uiview ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview

I want to create UIView with bezier curved so I am implementing following code but I not getting what i exactly want.

```
self.test = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, [[UIScreen mainScreen]bounds].size.width, [[UIScreen mainScreen]bounds].size.height)];
self.test.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];

[self.view addSubview:self.test];

UIBezierPath *myClippingPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];
[myClippingPath moveToPoint:CGPointMake(0, 150)];


[myClippingPath addCurveToPoint:CGPointMake([[UIScreen mainScreen]bounds].size.width, 100)
              controlPoint1:CGPointMake(0, 0)
              controlPoint2:CGPointMake([[UIScreen mainScreen]bounds].size.width, 100)];
[myClippingPath addCurveToPoint:CGPointMake(0, 225)
                 controlPoint1:CGPointMake(0, 100)
                  controlPoint2:CGPointMake([[UIScreen mainScreen]bounds].size.width, 225)];




CAShapeLayer *mask = [CAShapeLayer layer];
mask.path = myClippingPath.CGPath;

self.test.layer.mask = mask;
```

Here I got the following output but i want the same curve in both side top and bottom as i have in bottom side.
[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RNISf.png)

[Needed output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dTWTW.png)

Comment: check out this http://www.raywenderlich.com/34003/core-graphics-tutorial-curves-and-layers

Comment: What is your desired output, What should you want your view be in ?

Comment: i need this as output [needed output](http://postimg.org/image/bclxkknkl/)